# Jupyter/Ipython notebook autosave during execution

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to autosave the notebook while e kernel is running and a cell is being executed?
Everytime I execute a cell for a long time it stops autosaving and it starts saving again after the cell execution is finished. 
Is this the default behavior? 
Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autosaving is always running on a timer, regardless of execution. However, the autosave event only fires if there are changes to save (indicated via a so-called 'dirty' flag). Output arriving sets that flag, which might be why you see autosave resuming once execution completes (more precisely, it should be when output arrives).

If you are making changes and autosave isn't happening, then there might be a bug in how the notebook tracks its dirty state.

Comment: Could it be because the output is updating frequently and the timer restarts every time the output changes?

Comment: Indeed, you've found a dirty state bug just like I mentioned above. New output doesn't set the dirty flag until the last output arrives. [This should fix it](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/1807). *Other* changes to the document, such as adding/removing cells, or modifying cell contents, should still trigger dirty-state while execution is happening.